# Command not found error after installing xming

Tags: xming

I installed `xming` (6.9.0.31) in my Windows system and checked the "Enable X11 forwarding" box in   putty but no output

```
Command :xclock
-bash: xclock: command not found
```

What are the other configuratons I need to check.

Comment: Welcome to the site. (1) Your question seems to be about configuring the windows side, which is off-topic here. (2) What did you do that led to the error message. (3) What do you mean by "no output" - you seem to be getting at least the error message, so what output did you expect?

Comment: The question is regarding Windows. It belongs on Superuser.